# Webfonts-loader: Override icons with the same name

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using [webfonts-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webfonts-loader) to generate a font from SVGs. I have two locations from where I load icons and I want to be able to override icons with the same name, but webpack throws an error:
`Error: The glyph name "foo" must be unique.`

```
module.exports = {
  files: ['./folder1/*.svg', `../../folder2/*.svg`],
  fontName: 'my-icons',
  classPrefix: 'my-',
  baseSelector: '.myicon',
  types: ['woff2'],
  fileName: 'my.[fontname].[hash:6].[ext]',
}
```

*folder1* includes *foo.svg* and *bar.svg* and *folder2* includes *foo.svg*.

Is that possible somehow? I couldn't find any option for that.